# SSL/TLS cipher suites

Tags: tls

Which factors affect the cipher suites lists?

Me and my friend are both using Internet Explorer, which support the same version of SSL TLSv1.2, and the cipher suites lists are different.

Note: our browser versions are different.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are asking about the list of cipher suites sent from the client to the server in the [first message of the TLS handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake). A browser needs configuration, and potentially code, to implement a cipher suite. As changing the configuration and code requires development and (lots of) testing, browser vendors frequently don't bother to port all cipher suites to all supported browsers. In part this is due to laziness, though spending effort to support the latest-and-greatest cipher suite if it is not widely used by servers does seem like a poor use of limited resources.

So browser vendors try to choose a set of cipher suites that will provide universal connectivity with servers as well as sufficient security.

Over time, browsers tend to add stronger cipher suites to their implementation and drop support for weaker suites.

The exact set of available cipher suites varies from one version of SSL/TLS to the next. The Wikipedia has a [nice table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Cipher) showing how old cipher suites have become insecure and were then dropped from later versions of the the protocol. You can see the [draft list cipher suites](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-11#page-99) for upcoming TLS 1.3 protocol.